# How to change the view in one tab of an UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbar

I set up an iOS App with Swift and XCode 11. I'm using an UITabBar Controller and linked it with UIViews in my Storyboard. So my TabBar has three entries called VC-A, VC-B and VC-C.

Now I want to have a fourth view called VC-D which should be accessible from VC-A but in which I also can navigate back to VC-A. 
The Tab bar should also be still visible to navigate from VC-D to VC-B and from VC-D to VC-C, but not back.

I tried just to link from first to the second view via the StoryBoard but the TabBar disappears in the second view.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to be a little more precise with your question... What exactly do you mean by *"change the view"*? Assuming you have VC-A VC-B and VC-C as the three view controllers for the tabs, do you want a button in VC-A to switch to Tab-B? Or, do you have a fourth view controller - VC-D - and you want to navigate from VC-A to VC-D while keeping Tab-A selected? And, would you then want to navigate **back** to VC-A?

Comment: Hey @DonMag, thank you for your response. I updated the question using your model, hoping it's more precise this time.